# How can I block a program from accessing the Internet?

Tags: windows-7, internet, firewall, blocking, connection

I really want to know how can I prevent a program to connect to Internet with Windows 7 firewall?

I have smart security nod32 business edition installed on my computer.
should i do this job with nod or there is a way in Windows Firewall?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Basically you do this to prevent a program from connecting to the Internet:

1. From start menu, search for "Firewall" and select `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`
2. Choose Outbound Rules from the tree at the left.
3. Choose `New Rule...` from the menu at the right.
4. `New Outbound Rule Wizard` opens. This is really easy now:

   a. Select `Program` as rule type.

   b. Select the program's EXE file.

   c. Choose `Block the connection`.
5. Choose the profile this rule applies to. If in doubt, select all three.
6. Add the descriptive name (you may want to delete this rule later).

You're done.

Comment: Windows Firewall is definitely the easiest way to go.

Comment: For Windows XP?

Comment: For those of you wondering I'd like to note that you don't need to restart the application or anything; The rule takes effect immediately.

Comment: Just tried on a setup.exe and still can access the internet. Doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: What to do on 4b if the app is installed from Microsoft Store?

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent the program from accessing the internet through Windows Firewall.

Or if you know the address it tries to connect to simply add a rule in you hosts file and let it connect to your loopback address :-)

```
 c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

 127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use a 3rd party outbound firewall, [this is a good one](http://www.sphinx-soft.com/Vista/order.html), they have a Free and a Paid version, Free one works well.

.