# How to create an outbound rule for a program via the command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, script, firewall

I have several programs that I'd like to block from accessing the Internet. A manual (i.e. point-and-click) solution is described [here](https://superuser.com/a/363574).

Is there a way to do it via the command line on Windows 10?

Something like this pseudocode:

```
firewall --create --outbound --name "myRule" --target "C:\some\program.exe"
```

It could be either CMD or PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Powershell, try the following:

```ps
New-NetFirewallRule -Direction Outbound -Program “C:\some\program.exe” -Action Block -Profile All -DisplayName “Block My Program.exe” -Description “Block My Program.exe”
```

This will block for all profiles: Domain, Private and Public. If you want to block only for a particular profile, change `-Profile All` to `-Profile Public` if you want to block for public networks or `-Profile Domain, Private` if you want to block for domain and private networks.

If you don't have the New-NetFirewallRule commandlet, install the NetSecurity module:

```ps
Install-Module -Name NetSecurity
```

Comment: What if even `The term 'Install-Module' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...` in PowerShell ?

Comment: @sprsr Install PowershellGet package so you can use Install-Module cmdlet. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7.2